# What possibilities would cause Bootstrap Grid system not work properly?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I had something weird happen with the BootStrap grid system, everything worked fine and I added the AspIdentity samples, and the grid system worked but then when I went and checked again, alot of things aren't the lengths they used to be. I double checked my markup in bootply and it worked but won't now in my project..
A sample of the code is this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtNewAdmin" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministrator"><b>Administrator</b></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="txtNewAdmin" type="text" class="form-control" name="administrator" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorPassword"><b>Password</b></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input id="btnResetAdminPassword" type="button" value="Reset" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtConfirmPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorConfirmPassword"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="txtConfirmPassword" type="text" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtAdministratorEmail" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorEmail"><b>Email</b></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="txtAdministratorEmail" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like now:

[image: What it looks like now with the above code]

as you can see by the code that its not looking as the code would suggest, the textfields length should be all the way to the reset button.

I have no idea what happened, is there anything I should check or has anyone had something similar happen?

**EDIT**
I should also add that all my views are affected the same way.

**More Completed code and new screen shot**

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Dealers" data-toggle="tab">Dealers</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Profile">
            <br />
            <fieldset class="Myfieldset">
                <legend class="Mylegend">Profile</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorUserName" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorUserName"><b>Username:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="txtModeratorUser" type="text" class="form-control" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorPassword"><b>Password:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="txtModeratorPassword" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorVerifyPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorVerifyPassword"><b>Verify Password:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="txtModeratorVerifyPassword" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorModerator" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorModerator"><b>Manufacturer:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="txtModeratorModerator" type="text" class="form-control" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorCatalogVersion" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorCatalogVersion"><b>Catalog Version:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="txtModeratorCatalogVersion" type="text" class="form-control" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorEmail" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorEmail"><b>Email:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="txtModeratorEmail" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">
                        <input id="btnUpdateModerator" type="button" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <input id="btnResetModerator" type="button" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="Dealers">
            <br />
            <fieldset class="Myfieldset">
                <legend class="Mylegend">Users</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="acModeratorDealer" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorDealer"><b>Dealer:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="acModeratorDealer" type="text" class="form-control" name="dealer" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorUserPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorUserPassword"><b>Password:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="txtModeratorUserPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="dealerpassword" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorVerifyUserPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorVerifyUserPassword"><b>Verify Password:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="txtModeratorVerifyUserPassword" type="text" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtModeratorUserEmail" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblModeratorUserEmail"><b>Email:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="txtModeratorUserEmail" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="msManufacturerCatalog" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerCatalog"><b>Catalog:</b></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select id="msManufacturerCatalog" multiple name="catalog"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><h4><b>Address</b></h4></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerAddress1">Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerAddress1" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="address" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerAddress2" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerAddress2">Address2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerAddress2" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerCity" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerCity">City</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerCity" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="city" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerState" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerState">State</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerState" type="text" class="form-control" name="state" />
                            </div>
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerZip" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerZip">Zip/Postal</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerZip" type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="acDealerCountry" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerCity">Country</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="acCountry" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="country" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><h4><b>Contact</b></h4></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerContact" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerContact">Contact</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerContact" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="contact" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerPhone" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerPhone">Phone</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerPhone" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="phone" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerWorkPhone" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerWork">Work</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerWorkPhone" type="text" class="form-control max-size" name="work" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerFax" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerFax">Fax</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerFax" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerMobile" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerMobile">Mobile</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerMobile" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="txtManufacturerDealerOther" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufacturerDealerOther">Other</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <input id="txtManufacturerDealerOther" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                                <input id="btnSaveDealerInfo" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                <input id="btnCancelDealerInfo" type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <br/>
            <fieldset class="Myfieldset">
                <legend class="Mylegend">Current Users</legend>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some areas are affected, so I am wondering if something got changed when I installed the aspidentity samples from nuget

[image: Only certain areas being affected]

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Eric, I am using 3.3.4

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure which browser you are using but it worked for me once I added the `class` [`form-horizontal`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) to the `form` tag around your content.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtNewAdmin" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministrator"><b>Administrator</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="txtNewAdmin" type="text" class="form-control" name="administrator" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorPassword"><b>Password</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="txtPassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input id="btnResetAdminPassword" type="button" value="Reset" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtConfirmPassword" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorConfirmPassword"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="txtConfirmPassword" type="text" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAdministratorEmail" class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblAdministrationAdministratorEmail"><b>Email</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="txtAdministratorEmail" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I actually do have everything wrapped in a 
<div class="form-control">
....
</div>
there is alot more code, this was just a snippet

Comment: I think that may be your problem then.  [`form-control`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example) is only used supposed to be used to format HTML form elements, not `div`s.

Comment: I just tried using a form tag instead of a div and its the same issue. I really have no idea what happened..I'm looking at my views in a browser and it looks to be only certain things are being affected, I'll post a pic of one of my other views and its code and you'll see it only affects certain areas

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap grid system is made out of 12 columns not 8 as you're telling your code to use, if you change either the `col-md-6` to `col-md-8` or the `col-md-2` to `col-md-4` your page should work just fine.

You can read all about hte grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried changing the cols to be larger but same effect, this had worked fine earlier